# Flex DropDown selection not working when I search for item

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, drop-down-menu

so here is the problem that I have so far. I tried to simplify my code so I can attempt to figure this out, but I have had absolutely no luck. I have a viewstack that contains 1 dropdown per stack. They share the same data provider. What I want to do is to select the item contents from the first one. Once I do that, when I click a button to the next stack I have a function that searches from index 0 to the dataprovider length and if the item from the first stack matches the second one, I want to have the second dropdown pick that item up and display it. I have it matching, and I try to select it, but when I run the application it shows up like nothing is selected. Here is what I have:

edit: I got it to work for a simple example, but when I attempt to use it in my more complicated example, on that button click it for some reason resets the value of selectedIndex to -1. How do I prevent this from happening? This is working code for the simple example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="popList()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        [Bindable]
        private var myList : ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var selectedItem : String;

        [Bindable]
        private var index : int;

        [Bindable]
        private var ind : int;

        private function popList() : void {
            myList = new ArrayCollection();
            stack.initialize();
            myList.addItem("1");
            myList.addItem("2");
            myList.addItem("3");
            myList.addItem("4");
            myList.addItem("5");
            myList.addItem("6");
            first.initialize();
            second.initialize();
        }

        private function goNext() : void {
            selectedItem = first.selectedItem;
            stack.selectedChild = stackb;

            for(index = 0; index < myList.length; index++){
                var itemNow : String = myList[index].toString();
                if(selectedItem == myList[index].toString()){
                    ind = index;
                }
            }

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:ViewStack id="stack" width="862" height="500">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="stacka">
        <s:DropDownList x="317" y="174" id="first" dataProvider="{myList}"></s:DropDownList>
        <s:Button id="next" x="335" y="263" label="Next" click="goNext()"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="stackb">
        <s:DropDownList x="317" y="174" id="second" dataProvider="{myList}" selectedIndex="{ind}"></s:DropDownList>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>



</s:Application>
```

Comment: +1 for trying to put together a sample as simple as possible.  Thank You!

Comment: I got my simple example to work... The issue I am now having is when I load the page in my more complicated project, it resets the value of selectedIndex to -1. Any thoughts on that? I edited my question to reflect the changes and update in question.

Comment: I posted a full answer; you really need to be careful about that code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try to run the code, but I have a bunch of observations:

1. First, don't use the same dataProvider for two separate DropDownLists.  It causes weird issues.  It makes no sense, I have no idea why; but it does.  You could dupe the dataProvider by creating a second collection using the same source.  Something like this:

-

```
second.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(myList.source);
```

1. Second, you shouldn't have to manually call the initialize method on either of the DropDownLists.  That is highly unusual.  The initialize event is fired as part of the creation process; and I assume the initialization method is part of the default event handler.  But, firing that event is not the same as having the component go through it's Lifecycle process.
2. A ViewStack doesn't initialize it's children before the view changes.  So, you are probably setting the selectedIndex on the second DropDownList before that DropDownList is initialized, possibly allowing that drop down list to get lost.  You can combat this by setting the creationPolicy to all on the ViewStack.
3. You can probably solve this issue with binding.  Something like this.

-

```
<s:DropDownList x="317" y="174" id="second" dataProvider="{myList}" selectedIndex="{first.selectedIndex}"></s:DropDownList>
```

1. Your code to select the next item is comparing an object to a string, so you'll hever the selectedItem.

You could change your loop to something like this:

```
        for(index = 0; index < myList.length; index++){
            if(selectedItem == myList[index]){
                second.selectedIndex = index;
            }
        }
```

1. But, if you're using the same dataProvider, or a copy of it, why do you even need the loop?  Just use the selectedIndex property:

-

```
second.selectedIndex = first.selectedIndex
```

Does that help?

Note: StackOverflow makes it real hard to do code formatting inside a list; sorry for not keeping the numbers in my list.

Comment: Okay, so first of all thank you for the great response and also thank you for helping me tweak my coding conventions, as I am still fairly new to flex development. I tried to change the creationPolicy to all for the view stack, and it selects it briefly, then out of nowhere it disappears and deselects what was originally selected. So if I had a list containing {red, white, blue, green} and it selects white, it will appear for a millisecond then the dropdown will look like nothing was chosen at all.

Comment: EDIT: FIXED. I got it to run. Thank you again for everything. The reason it wasn't appearing was that my code essentially removed the array before regenerating it when refreshing my data. It is best to use the refresh() function over creating a new structure. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't catch the recreation of the collection.  That is an issue when "saving" the selectedItem as a reference.  When you add or remove data to a collection, or change the sort or filter, the list classes should pick it up automatically.  You only need to call refresh() if you are changing the sort, or filter, and want to update the collection.  You only need to reset the dataProvider if you want to replace it.